# Equivalence criteria of integrable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(E,M)\to(\bar {\mathbb R}, B(\bar{\mathbb R}))$ be a non-negative measurable function. For $k\in \mathbb Z$, consider the sets

$$E_k=\{x\in E, f(x)>2^k\},$$
$$F_k=\{x\in E, 2^k < f(x)\leq 2^{k+1}\}.$$

Show the following assertions are equivalent:

1. $f$ is integrable;
2. $\Sigma_{k\in \mathbb Z}2^k\mu(F_k)<\infty$
3. $\Sigma_{k\in \mathbb Z}2^k\mu(E_k)<\infty$

Here is my thought:

For 1 to 2, it is intuitive that because it is just the integral of a step function bounded above by $f$ has finite integral. However, any idea from 2 to 3 and 3 to 1?? What does the sum in 3 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably clearer what the sum in 3. means if we write it as

$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{k+1}\mu(F_k).\tag{1}$$

It's the integral of a step function that bounds $f$ from above.

To see that $(1)$ is indeed another way to write the sum in 3:

$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^k\mu(E_k) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}2^k\mu\left(\bigcup_{m=k}^\infty F_m\right) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{m=k}^\infty 2^k\mu(F_m) = \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^m 2^k\mu(F_m) = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} 2^{m+1}\mu(F_m).$$

The second equality holds since the $F_m$ are disjoint.

Comment: Why the third equality in answer is true?

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \sum_{m=k}^\infty 2^k\mu(F_m) = \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k=-\infty}^m 2^k\mu(F_m)\,?$$ That holds since all terms in the sum are non-negative, so we can change the order of summation.

Comment: I do not understand the last equality.Please explain about it? thanks

Comment: The last is just $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^m 2^k = 2^{m+1}.$$ You can sum in the other direction, and shift indices to get $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^m 2^k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{m-n} = 2^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} = 2^m\frac{1}{1-\frac12}.$$